# login and fetch url Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, authentication, urlfetch

I am trying to fetch data from this website into my google spreadsheet using Google Apps Scripts:
https://net.statev.de/#/pages/buisness/storage/5aec8c9a3b82972b99e741c6

And need to login here first:
https://net.statev.de/#/login

This is the function i came up with:

```
function fetch() {
var loginURL = 'https://net.statev.de/#/login';
  var dataURL = 'https://net.statev.de/#/pages/buisness/storage/5aec8c9a3b82972b99e741c6';
  var loginPayload = {
     'email':'testmail',
     'password':"test",
  };
  var loginOptions = {'method':'post','payload':loginPayload,'followredirects':false};
  var loginResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(loginURL,loginOptions);

  var loginHeaders = loginResponse.getAllHeaders();
  var cookie = [loginResponse.getAllHeaders()["Set-Cookie"]];
  cookie[0] = cookie[0].split(";")[0];
  cookie = cookie.join(";");

  var dataHeaders = {'Cookie':cookie};
  var dataOptions = {'method':'get','headers':dataHeaders};
  var dataResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(dataURL,dataOptions);

  Logger.log(dataResponse);
}
```

My problem here is, I only get 404 Error from the UrlFetchApp.fetch and i don't really get what I am doing wrong.
Is it possible that the website blocks my fetch request?

Comment: Contact them to see if they have an API for which you can use traditional key, client id, secret key, etc. They may have one, or they may not. PS: your code has two `.fetch` calls

Comment: @tehhowch The 1st one is to obtain the cookie?

Comment: @AntonDementiev OP says the `.fetch` call gives a 404, but don't say which one.

Comment: @tehhowch yep i forgot to mention it's the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registration form doesn't work, so I couldn't test this. That said, it seems that you are not calling the correct authorization endpoint. You can use Chrome Dev Tools as a network sniffer

[image]
[image]

It's extremely likely that using just the login & password combo will not do the job - if it does work, the website you link to is lousily programmed and not secure.

To sum up, here's the data:

> https://net.statev.de/auth/login

Payload properties

```
 {"password": password, "username": username}
```

Comment: @Torba_Trike Does that answer your question? If so, please consider marking it as resolved

Comment: the first problem is solved but now i get anotherone. Sorry for just commenting i am new here and need to get used to the comment and answering system

Comment: @Torba_Trike StackOverflow is for asking genuine questions, not for debugging someone else's code line by line. If you want people to build the entire project for you, just hire someone.

Comment: @Torba_Trike you should tick this off http://prntscr.com/jgzd6b The tick symbol will become green